# Getting issue in android webview Text alignment

Tags: android, webview

I am new to android. I am developing epub reader for android devices. webview shows text in left alignment. i want it to be justify. i am not sure this is text alignment problem.

This is my webview settings:

```
final WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mainWebView.loadUrl("my html page");// loding my html pages here
    mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

i used this code for text alignment

```
mainWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) { " +  
        "var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];"+
           "if (mySheet.addRule) { " +  
           "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"    +   
           "} else {"+
           "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"+
           "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);" +
           "}"+
           "})addCSSRule(selector, newRule)");  
  mainWebView.loadUrl("javascript:addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;');");
```

if i remove  `mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);` means i am getting justify text.

Screenshot of webview:

[image]

i want it to be like this:

[image]

i don't know whats wrong in my code. `mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);` allows to zoom. don't know why it kills text alignment. please help me to overcome this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [this guy](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/06/justify-text-inside-webview-in-android/) it's pretty straightforward... and doesn't quite explain why your approach won't work.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am facing the same issue. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't seem like you're applying your webSettings to the web view. I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

so perhaps your javascript isn't firing because it's not on... ?